# Develop for Windows 8/Windows Phone 8 (Apollo)/Windows Phone 7 - WinRT (JavaScript) vs. Silverlight (C#)

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-8, windows-runtime

I am looking for the proper technology to start the **Metro Windows 8** application for tablet. The problem is that the application should run on **WP7** also and in the future on the **WP8** (Apollo).

My assumption is:

•   Silverlight is probably dead (even still supported in Windows 8)

•   Silverlight as I think will not be supported on WP8 (Apollo)

•   Even there will be still Silverlight support on WP8 I simply don’t want to use obsolete technology…

•   WP7 will not allow upgrade to WP8

For the Windows 8 Metro style application the only relevant choice seems to be the HTML/JavaScript, even there is possibility to use C#/C++ on the top of the WinRT.

This I think is choice of future, even it means develop the application twice once in HTML for Windows 8 and Apollo and once in C#/Silverlight for WP7.

Any other tips and suggestions?

Thanks a lot
STeN

Comment: Why do you think HTML/JavaScript is the only relevant choice?

Comment: What is the better option considering the Silverlight is going to die soon or later?

Comment: @STeN, this question might be more suitable to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why u are closing it??? Why this is not a real question? I am asking which technology I should use, what is wrong with this question? Why some people are being able to answer it?? This is aspect I HATE about the stackoverflow, that some GODs, who are not able to answer and help me simply close it... That's a North Korea politburo like voting approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because SL5 is the last planned release does not indicate that it will die any time soon. You can still accomplish a lot with it, and it should be considered as part of your strategy.

C# / XAML (with many WPF-like features, like Binding, MVVM, etc...) is a supported platform for Windows 8 Metro Apps: [Create your first Metro style app using C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211380.aspx)

Using C# allows for much more unified work across the platforms. Since you are already building a Metro App, and using that same (or similar) app for Windows Phone 7 / 8 you will have to maintain some variance in the projects; this will not change should you decide to go HTML5 / Javascript - unless you plan for the app to not take advantage of any Metro App capabilities, and want to level the whole thing through WinRT.

Comment: WPF is not supported in Metro Style Apps

Comment: Strictly correct, but... XAML - Databinding - MVVM - all very WPF-ey. =) Regardless I'll edit my answer to be more accurate.

Comment: Hi, but still for Windows 8 and might be Windows phone 8 I need to use C#/XAML, while on WP7 I need to use C#/Silverlight. So it's more a language question, since I still need to maintain 2 branches. in that aspect I more believe HTML5/JavaScript (also this is technology we can use outside of the Microsoft platform) then C#/XAML.

Comment: @STeN C#/XAML **IS** Silverlight. Also, according to numerous leaks on the internet, WinRT isn't "truly" coming to Windows Phone 8 for whatever reason. The only WinRT bits that are going to WP8 is C++ APIs and possibly Javascript. They're sticking with Silverlight as the primary .Net API.